# minimum requirements to run a java web application

Tags: java, hibernate, spring

which are the minimum requirements to run a java web application with spring 2.5 and Hibernate 3? I mean, referred to Tomcat version, Mysql version, and Java EE version. I use Java EE 6, Mysql 14.14 distrib 5.1.41 and Tomcat 7 but i need to know the lowest version in which can be run

Comment: Note: There's no such thing as "JavaEE 1.6".

Comment: java version "1.6.0_25-ea"   Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_25-ea-b01)

Comment: That's what is shown when i put "java -version" in cmd: java version "1.6.0_25-ea"   Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_25-ea-b01)

Comment: That's simply JDK/JRE/JSE version, not JavaEE.

Comment: and how could i get the javaEE version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would run on a reasonably low version of everything:

- spring runs on tomcat 5.5 for sure, which is way old (and might even run on 5.5)
- hibernate's MySQL Dialect should be fine with MySQL 4.1

For exact compatibility you should check release notes, but it is unreasonable to use so old version of these technologies anyway.

Comment: And Java EE version? That's what is shown when i put "java -version" in cmd: java version "1.6.0_25-ea"   Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_25-ea-b01)

Comment: java ee version doesn't matter since you are not using java ee. Only the servlet version matters, which comes bundled with tomcat